# How to know the usage of the command before I download through command

Tags: apt

I would like to know what's the purpose or usage before I use "apt-get install" to install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an Ubuntu website that has exactly that purpose. It's called [Ubuntu Apps Directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/). Just visit the Ubuntu Apps Directory website, and type the name of the app you want more information about in the search box next to where it says **Search for an app**. Then you'll get a fairly complete description of the app and also usually one or more screenshots. The screenshots start off small-sized, you can click on a screenshot to enlarge it to fullscreen.

Comment: It will be better if we could get it from command line

Comment: @王子1986 Run `apt-cache search some-regex-containing-part-of-package-name` to search the names and descriptions of all available packages and display the package name(s) and the short description(s). Run `apt-cache show package-name` to display a long description of the package like the description of the package you would see in the Ubuntu Software Center. For more info about using apt-cache type `man apt-cache`.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the source and read the README file inside.

```
apt-get source package-name
```